# Comparing gcrypt MD5 outputs to a existing hash

Tags: c, hash, md5, libgcrypt

I been given an MD5 output (a 16 byte hex string) and I need to figure out what the message used to make the hash was.

I want to compare it with the output of gcrypts `gcry_md_hash_buffer()`, but I'm sure how to declare it in such a way that `strcmp()` will know the two are the same.

I had tried this earlier:

```
char answerHash[16] = {0x57, 0x50, 0x1a, 0xc7, 0xb9, 0xd5, 0x44, 0x0a, 0xde, 0xe8, 0xb3, 0xdd, 0x97, 0x09, 0x72, 0xcb};
```

But that ended up eating part of a different string when I tried printf()

Sample of the problem area:

```
gcry_md_hash_buffer(GCRY_MD_MD5, result, answerString, strlen(answerString));

char answerHash[16] = {0x57, 0x50, 0x1a, 0xc7, 0xb9, 0xd5, 0x44, 0x0a, 0xde, 0xe8, 0xb3, 0xdd, 0x97, 0x09, 0x72, 0xcb};

if(strcmp(result, answerHash) == 0){
printf("strcmp() works.\n");
}
```

EDIT: I don't think I'm explaining this correctly.  Let's try again.

The prof has a secret message, and has given us it's MD5 hash output.  He wants us to write a program to find the original message through brute force.

The message is 11 char long, but he's already told us what 5 of the chars are.  From this, I guessed the secret message, but I still have to write the program. :(

I already have the MD5 part working, but I need to figure out how to get the output I get from my MD5 against the MD5 he's given us.

In other words, I need way to declare a variable so that it contains the profs hash, and can be compared (by strcmp() or memcmp(), I'm not picky) to the output I get from gcry_md_hash_buffer().

EDIT2:

Antoine's got it.  memcmp() does the trick!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use `memcmp` which assumes fixed-sized array instead of `strcmp` which assumes zero-terminated strings, since your hash may contain zeros.

Second, I don't know where `answerString` comes from, but if you're doing a brute force search you're not sure to recover the original string, just a string which has the same MD5 hash. That may or may not bee enough for your purposes.

Otherwise, I'm not sure what's your problem:

```
    #include <string.h>
    static const char a[16] = {0x57, 0x50, 0x1a, 0xc7, 0xb9, 0xd5, 0x44, 0x0a, 0xde, 0xe8, 0xb3, 0xdd, 0x97, 0x09, 0x72, 0xcb};
    static const char b[16] = {0x57, 0x50, 0x1a, 0xc7, 0xb9, 0xd5, 0x44, 0x0a, 0xde, 0xe8, 0xb3, 0xdd, 0x97, 0x09, 0x72, 0xcb};
    return memcmp(a, b, 16); // => returns 0
```

Now, you mentionned `printf`. I hope you're not doing `printf(a)` ? Because your hash is an array of char, or `char*` which in `C` unfortunately also happens to be the type of strings. But the crucial difference between the two is that C-strings are zero-terminated. That means that every function accepting a string, such as `printf` or `strlen` excepts its `char*` input to be terminated by a `0`. If it's not the case it will **dangerously** scan the memory outside of your variable until it finds a 0 byte.

Comment: It's for a school assignment.  No Black Hats here.

Comment: I actually already figured out (guessed) the original message (457 is cool), which is what answerString is.

The program has to brute force the message by making a string, sending it through MD5, then comparing the resulting hash to the hash we've been given.  The problem is that I don't know how to get the given hash into the program in such a way that strcmp (or memcmp) will find a match.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, sorry. Could you try to explain what you mean by "how to get the given hash into the program in such a way that memcmp will find a match" ?

Comment: maybe you're trying to display hashes with printf? As explained in my edit that would be quite ugly :\